# Creating an add list function in haskell without using embedded methods

Tags: haskell

Using my zip function(see below), write a function addpairs that takes two lists [x0; x1; ... ; xn] and [y0; y1; ... ; ym] and returns the list [x0 + y0; x1 + y1; ... ; xp + yp], where p = min(n; m). Where this is the output from console.

```
*Recursion> :t addpairs
addpairs :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
*Recursion> addpairs [1,2,3,4] [40,50,60,90]
[41,52,63,94]
```

my zip function:

```
zip [] _ = []
zip _ [] = []
zip (a:aa) (b:bb) = (a,b) : Recursion.zip aa bb
```

Any help would be great.

**I actually solved this problem**
This was the solution I came up with:

```
addpairs xs ys = map f (Recursion.zip xs ys)
  where f (x,y) = x + y
```

Thanks for all that helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `xs` and `ys` are the two lists your function is given, then `zip xs ys` will be a list of tuples of numbers to add:

```
GHCi> zip [1,2,3,4] [40,50,60,90]
[(1,40),(2,50),(3,60),(4,90)]
```

`zip xs ys` will have the type `[(a,a)]` for some numeric type `a`. Next, take a look at the type of `map`:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Your function should look like this:

```
addpairs xs ys = map f (zip xs ys)
  where f ...
```

where `f` should be a function taking an `(a, a)` to be added and returning the resulting `a`. That should help you fill in the rest.

Comment: So I am really new to haskell and I am still trying to figure out how everything works.  so the actual syntax of putting functions together is a little hard for me now.  Basically I don't understand what that means.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to hopefully help show what the structure of the resulting `addpairs` definition should be.

Comment: I'm still having issues this is what i put:
    addpairs xs ys = f (Recursion.zip xs ys)
      where f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : addpairs f xs ys

Comment: @thehobbit21: `f` doesn't need to handle the whole list; it just needs to add two numbers, given as a tuple.

Answer (score 3):

You almost have the solution written down in your zip function.
But instead of adding the two associated values a and b you construct a tuple from them.

Why, given that you want to add them?

Comment: I dont understand your question.

Comment: Really? Think again. You have two lists `as` and `bs` and want as result a list where the corresponding elements are added, right? So, ask yourself what would be the result if you had written `a+b : Recursion.zip as bs` instead of `(a,b): Recursion.zip as bs`